# Set mouse or keyboard button to simulate left click and hold or rapid left click repeating in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse

Does anyone know a way to configure Windows 7 or use third party software to do this? I would like to click my middle mouse button and have it tell Windows to left click and hold until I click the middle mouse button again. A keyboard key would be fine as well.

Some games and apps have me holding down the left mouse button for a long time and I would like to reduce the stress on my mouse hand. Also, I would like to do a similar thing but have it repeatedly click the left mouse button automatically if possible.

If none of that is possible, how about temporalily setting a keyboard key to achieve a left mouse button emulation?

Comment: this may be built into Windows- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Whats-new-in-Ease-of-Access-Accessibility -I can't check on this machine (so haven't made this an answer) but I'm sure the option to click on click off existed for users with difficulties using mice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can create all your custom keyboard shortcuts using autohotkey. Autohotkey is a free open source software for macro and key binds.

http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: It would have been better to provide an actual script to do it.

Comment: Script for autohotkey that binds a keyboard shortcut to a mouse click: http://superuser.com/a/913791/295795

Answer (score 12):

[MouseKeys](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-keyboard-mouse-xp-45368.html) is built into windows XP and higher.

> Step 1 Turn on MouseKeys in Windows XP by pressing “Left-Alt,
>   "Left-Shift" and "NumLock” simultaneously. Press “Enter” to select
>   “Yes” in the dialog box that appears to activate MouseKeys.
>
> Step 2 Move the mouse pointer left and right by pressing “4” and “6”
>   on the numeric keypad. Press “8” and “2” to move the pointer up or
>   down. The “1”, “3”, “7” and “9” keys move the mouse pointer
>   diagonally.
>
> Step 3 Simulate a left mouse click by pressing “5." Press “+” to
>   double-click. Press “-“ and then “5” to right-click.
>
> Step 4 Drag and drop by moving the mouse with the numeric keypad.
>   Press “Insert” to simulate holding down the mouse button, and then
>   press the “Delete” key to release.

Comment: Many laptops and keyboard lack numpad, which is required for this to work. Furthermore, the keys are not rebindable, and so cumbersome to use that it's a worse solution than to click.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the autohotkey script that will bind a keyboard shortcut (CTRL + g) to a mouse click.

```
^g::
click
```

Save this in notepad with the file extension .ahk then compile with autohotkeys.  To compile autohotkeys scripts you will need to download it here:

http://www.autohotkey.com/

Also You can replace the key `g` with any letter to change the trigger key.  To change from CTRL to ALT replace the `^` with `!`.  For a complete list of symbols defining hotkeys see this documentation...

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Answer (score 3):

Autohotkey script for mapping a key to left mouse button (and hold while keeping key pressed), if key combined with SHIFT, the right mouse button will be clicked instead of the left.
I used the `

```
`::  ;backtick (tilde) key
click Down left ;click left mousebutton and hold
keywait,`` ; wait until key is released. Double backtick because backtick needs to be escaped (with a backtick)
click Up left ; release left mousebutton
return

^`::  ;backtick (tilde) key
click Down right ;click left mousebutton and hold
keywait, ^` ; wait until key is released. 
click Up right ; release left mousebutton
return
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this one & setting a key for left click. Set it to hold the key & click from 0-9999 clicks/second

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastclicker/

Answer (score 2):

Try a combination of:

a) mouse click emulating software (e.g. http://softboy.net/key/index.htm )

and

b) macro editor (e.g. http://robotask.com/ ).

Answer (score 1):

There is a brilliant free open source successor of project fastclicker resides at sourceforge too. It is called "The Windows Intel Fastest Mouse Clicker" (google it). That application uses modern SendInput() system call instead of obsolete mouse_event() in fastclicker. Also "The Windows Intel Fastest Mouse Clicker" is heavily optimized with Intel C/C++ compiler 15.0.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/fast-mouse-clicker-pro/

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. It will let you assign a key to do 1 or more clicks, or click repeatedly, but will NOT let you assign a key to a mouse button. You cannot hold the mouse button by holding down the keys, do drag and drop, and so on. 

Furthermore, if you want to do repeated clicks, well, unfortunately this will lead to a pause between the first clicks and the repeated clicks. So for someone who wants repeated clicks, this is nevertheless a bad solution and far from brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this one, very helpful:

http://rhdesigns.browseto.org/mouseemulator.html

> "Mouse Emulator" This program is freeware. If you really like this
> program, and want to make a donation,  please go to the website for
> more information. Thank you.
>
> The program runs under windows NT/9x and above.
>
> **Manual**
>
> The program recognizes the following keys: (NumLock must be ON!)
> Keypad 1 - Left mouse button
>
> Keypad 2 - Right mouse button
>
> Keypad 3 - Middle mouse button
>
> Keypad 4, 5, 6, 8 - Moves the mouse left, down, right or up respectively.
>
> Keypad 7 - Mousewheel up (Scroll)
>
> Keypad 9 - Mousewheel down (Scroll)
>
> Keypad / - Toggle Left mouse button (Useful for RSI users)
>
> Keypad * - Toggle Right mouse button (Useful for RSI users)
>
> Keypad - - Toggle Middle mouse button (Useful for RSI users)
>
> Ctrl + Keypad 0 - Enable/Disable Mouse emulator
>
> You can exit Mouse Emulator by right clicking on the mouse icon in the
> taskbar.
>
> Adjusting the mouse speed: Double click on one of the .reg files and
> restart the program to change the mouse speed. For instance
> double-click on SlowMouseSpeed.reg and restart the program if you
> think the mouse speed of mouse emulator is too high.
>
> For advanced users: If you want to adjust the mouse speed, you can use
> regedit to change the registry values.
>
> Known Problems: Mouse Emulator does not work with MS-Dos prompts (9x)
> Mouse Emulator does not work with DirectX Mouse Input (DirectInput)

Answer (score 0):

I use The Windows Intel Fastest Mouse Clicker too. A week ago they fixed a bug, and this app is 100 times faster now than FastClicker by xytor mentioned above by Michael (with the bug it was 10 times faster).

Also I watched at source code of The Windows Intel Fastest Mouse Clicker and adopt it for Java in my current projects. Hint:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
...
User32.INSTANCE.SendInput(...);
```

https://sourceforge.net/projects/fast-mouse-clicker-pro/

Answer (score -1):

Hi I just found an other useful way to do this in Windows 7.

1) Seach for "Mouse" for where you search for program and files. Then click on the result which should open "Mouse Properties".

2) Click on "ClickLock" which enable to highlight or drag without holding down the mouse button.

3) Click on "Settings" to adjust the time before the "script" is activated.